# T-SQL вывод одной таблицы два раза

Tags: sql, sql-server

только начал изучать T-SQL у меня есть таблица (Cars) следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо вывести таблицу следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. необходимо объединить таблицы исключив из второй Car с id = 1. Пытался через JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars A JOIN Cars B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id > 1
```

Но, результат не такой как хотелось бы (Убираются обе верхние строки с id = 1):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Cars A left JOIN Cars B ON A.id+1 = B.id
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое), оказывается решение было простое такое)